# On distances between points on the plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Take a set of $2n$ points in the plane and assume that no open set of diameter $1$ contains more than $n$ of these points.

Question: can we pair up the points so that the distance between the points in a pair is at least $1$?

Comment: Obviously false for $n=1$. For $n=2$ a counterexample is an equilateral triangle of side $1+\epsilon$ and it's center...

Comment: Gjergji Zaimi, why *false* for $n=1$?

Comment: Oops, I meant "obviously true for $n=1$". 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gjergi's $n=2$ counterexample, the center is an isolated point of the graph you'd like to match.  One way to save your question might simply rule that out.

But consider your question *without* the hypothesis:  When can we pair up $2n$ points so that the distance between the points in a pair is at least 1? General matching theory says yes, one can, whenever there is no Tutte obstruction.  That means whenever you can't remove $k$ points and leave a graph with more than $k$ odd components.  Now for two points to lie in distinct components is a strong condition: no path with big steps can connect them.  In particular the distance between the points cannot be more than 1, and they can't both lie more than 1 unit away from any common third point.

Now one can get many components of size 1 by having many points clustered close together, which is roughly what your hypothesis meant to rule out.  But even arranging points along a line, one can get many components and not all of them consisting of isolated points.

Hope that helps...sorry, don't have time to work this out further now.